# Windows7 64bit へGDALをインストールできない(Python3.4.4 32bit)

Tags: python, python3

**実現したいこと**

Windows7 64bit へGDALをインストールしたいと考えています。

**前提**

・Python 3.4.4 32bit 　(他ソフトとの連携のため、64bit版ではなく、32bit版が必要です。)
・Visual Studio C++2010再領布可能パッケージ
 ・GDALは以下から入手
http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7/mapserver-7.0.7-1600-core.msi
 http://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1600-gdal-2-2-3-mapserver-7-0-7/GDAL-2.2.3.win32-py3.4.msi

・環境変数については以下3つの設定を実施
-Path
 -Gdal-data
 -Gdal-driver-path

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

```
=========== RESTART: C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\サンプルプログラム\sample.py ===========
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\サンプルプログラム\sample.py", line 2, in <module>
 from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\site-packages\osgeo\init.py", line 21, in <module>
 _gdal = swig_import_helper()
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\site-packages\osgeo\init.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
 File "C:\Python34_32bit\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
 return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたプロシージャが見つかりません。
```

**補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）**

エラー確認のため、他PC(Windows7 64bit)へPython3.4.4 64bitをインストールして、
 他は同一条件で、インストール作業を行ったところ、そちらについては、正常に動作することを
確認しています。

Answer (score 1):

GDALが用意したdllとは異なる同名のdll(他ソフトが用意したもの)を読み込むPath設定になっていたため、GDALが用意したdllを参照するように設定を見直し、解決しました。どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

デバッガーを使って、エラーメッセージにある、"C:\Python34_32bit\lib\imp.py", line 243 の場所にブレークポイントを置いて実行すると、ロードに失敗しているDLLのファイルの場所がわかるので、それと設定等を照合すると原因がわかるかもしれません。

そういうことが面倒であれば、Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages を使って見たらどうでしょうか。必要なバイナリーが含まれているのでインストールが楽です。

・ [GDAL](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。参考にさせていただきます